# What is the best method for overriding a nested DRF serializer so it creates an object if it doesn't exist?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework project that uses a nested UserSerializer throughout the app. An example would be a TicketSerializer with a nested UserSerializer for owner.

I would like for any time User data is serialized that it get_or_create the User without having to explicitly do this as part of the TicketSerializer create method.

I know there are probably a lot of ways to do this, so I’m trying to understand the most “correct” way.  Currently, I’m think about overriding the UserSerializer **init** method or create a custom Validator that would handle the logic. Ideally, this would be a solution that could be implemented as re-usable Mixin or Validator that could be easily propagated to several projects.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket

    def create(self, validated_data):
       user = validated_data.pop('user')
       user_obj = User.objects.get_or_create(**user)

       ticket = Ticket.objects.create(**validated_data, user=user_obj)
       return ticket
```

Comment: Writing a public API or internal one. This is seriously coupling your application modules which will be really difficult to decouple in the future if you need to. Why not two calls 1) Create the user, 2) Create the ticket?

Comment: This is for an extremely large application.  I'm not concerned about decoupling, I'm just looking for a way to remove the repeated logic of getting and creating a user every time the UserSerializer is used.

Comment: This info is in the DRF manual https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: The DRF manual describes my current solution, which is shown above.